# Correct way to get max JInt value from List[JValue] in Json4s

Tags: json, scala, json4s

Is there any particular reasons why Json4s haven't defined implicit Ordering?

For example this code::

```
List(JInt(1), JInt(3)).max
```

Raises following exception

> No implicit ordering defined for org.json4s.JsonAST.JInt

So, is it just a feature nobody cares about or there's some story behind that?

And also, is this implementation (It uses scalaz Order) is ok? Doesn't it violates the contract?

```
object JValueOrdering extends Order[JValue] {
  def order(x: JValue, y: JValue): Ordering = (x, y) match {
    case (JInt(a), JInt(b))         => a ?|? b
    case (JString(a), JString(b))   => a ?|? b
    case (JDouble(a), JDouble(b))   => a ?|? b
    case (JDecimal(a), JDecimal(b)) => a ?|? b
    case (JArray(a), JArray(b))     => a.length ?|? b.length
    case _                          => Ordering.EQ
  }
}
```